# SQL help reading value in XML column

Tags: sql, xml

Currently I have a column in a table defined as text with data that is formed as XML.

Example data would be:

```
<Attributes><Default>0</Default><Table>0=Monday
1=Tuesday
2=Wednesday
3=Thursday
4=Friday
5=Saturday
-1=Sunday
</Table><Visibility>0</Visibility></Attributes>
```

This column needs to join to another table that has the column Weekday with a value of 0 for Monday. I need to be able to look into this XML structure and get back Monday.

Table 1 structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [CNF_Right]
(
    [RightId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [Attribute] [text] NULL
)
```

Table 1 Data:

```
RightID          Attribute
-----------------------------------------------------
1                <Attributes><Default>0</Default> 
                  <Table>0=Monday
                         1=Tuesday
                         2=Wednesday
                         3=Thursday
                         4=Friday
                         5=Saturday
                         -1=Sunday
                   </Table>
                   <Visibility>0</Visibility>
                 </Attributes>
```

Table 2 structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [DATA_Right]
(
    [RightDataId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [WeekDay] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Table 2 data:

```
RightDataID             WeekDay
-------------------------------
1                       0
2                       -1
3                       5
```

When I am joining these two, I would want to return

```
Rightid    RightDataID    Weekday    WeekDayDescription
-------------------------------------------------------
1              1             0       Monday
1              2            -1       Sunday
1              3             5       Saturday
```

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: This design is awfully wrong... There are solutions, but before presenting one, I'd rather ask, if you have any chance to change this? I'd prefere to help you find a new design and transfer the data into respondant structures than to find a solution for this mess...

Comment: No,   This design was here when I got the job.   We are slowly getting this corrected but this is taking some time.  In the mean while they ask for a report.

Answer (score 0):

As I've told you in a comment before, this design is awful, but it is something you have to live with...

Try this out:

```sql
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE dbTest;
GO
Use dbTest;
GO
CREATE TABLE [CNF_Right]
(
    [RightId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [Attribute] [text] NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [DATA_Right]
(
    [RightDataId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [WeekDay] [int] NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT INTO [CNF_Right](Attribute) VALUES
('<Attributes><Default>0</Default><Table>0=Monday
1=Tuesday
2=Wednesday
3=Thursday
4=Friday
5=Saturday
-1=Sunday
</Table><Visibility>0</Visibility></Attributes>');
INSERT INTO [DATA_Right]([WeekDay])
VALUES(0),(-1),(5);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetWeekdayList(@RightId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH GetContent(TableContent) AS
(
    SELECT CAST(CAST(r.Attribute AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML).value('(/Attributes/Table/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM [CNF_Right] r
    WHERE r.RightId=@RightId
)
,SplitContent(AsXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(gc.TableContent,CHAR(13),CHAR(10)),CHAR(10)+CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),'=','</y><y>'),CHAR(10),'</y></x><x><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)
    FROM GetContent gc
)
SELECT x.value('y[1]','int') AS WeekdayIndex
      ,x.value('y[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS WeekdayName
FROM SplitContent sc
CROSS APPLY sc.AsXml.nodes('/x[y/text()]') A(x);
GO

SELECT *
FROM [DATA_Right] dr
INNER JOIN dbo.GetWeekdayList(1) AS wl ON wl.WeekdayIndex=dr.[WeekDay]

GO
USE master;
GO
--Careful with real data
--DROP DATABASE dbTest;
GO
```

### some explanation

After creating a test db I use your commands to create both tables.

Then I insert the XML and the rights values into these tables.

The magic is done within an inline table valued function `dbo.GetWeekdayList()`. This function will cast the `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and this to `XML`. This is needed to be able to retrieve the values within the XML using the `.value()` method.

The result is the list of values as one big string with linebreaks and `=` characters.

In a second step this string is splitted uses an XML trick, while the final `SELECT` will return the weekday's name and index as a derived table.

The final query will join the *iTVF* just as if it was a table.

### Hints

This will be slow.
`TEXT` is deprecated and will not be supported in future versions.
The XML has to be casted over and over - a very expensive operation.
The derived table has to be created over and over with tons of expensive string manipulations, casts and XML actions.
All this is computed on poor little Database Server. Your DBAs will love you...

I'd suggest to write this data into a properly designed helper table and join this.

On the long sight this design should be changed completely...